# How to Associate DAG Owner with Google OAuth User in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I'm using Google OAuth2 to authenticate in Airflow Version:1.10.2. If I set up a user as Admin, they can see all DAGs on the /home page, as expected, and also manipulate them as well. If I set them up as a 'User', they still see all of the DAGs, no matter what I set the "owner": to in the default_args within the DAG. The user does not have the ability to edit/run any of the DAGs however. I expected the DAGs to be filtered by only those owned by the user, based on the filter_by_owner environment variable referenced below.

I've noticed that the actual username associated with my company generated Google account is something like 'google_xxxxxxxxxxxxx', and I've tried that as well as 'FirstName LastName', and just 'FirstName'.

I have the following variables set on the Airflow server:

```
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__RBAC=true
ENV AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__FILTER_BY_OWNER=true
```

I'm using the FAB webserver_config.py file to set the auth type:

```
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "User"
```

Any thoughts on what I should try, or what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

@LoganX. I'm trying to set my Google Auth with Airflow in RBAC, but I'm missing something.

Can you post an example of how you configured your `webserver_config.py`? I think there is something wrong with my `OAUTH_PROVIDERS` section.